# syntax error at or near $1 value pg-promise node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, pg-promise

i have this code

```
this.createtablePy = function(){
 db.none("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $1 ( $2 serial NOT NULL, data jsonb", ["pyTable", "id_py"])
 .then(()=> 
 {
     console.log("done pyme table ");
 })
 .catch(error =>{
     console.log("Error; " + error);
 });
};
```

and i get this error (is a SQL error?)

```
Error; error: syntax error at or near "'pyTable'"
```

but when i try on this way, it's ok

```
this.createtablePy = function(){
 db.none("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pyTable ( id_py serial NOT NULL, data jsonb")
 .then(()=> 
 {
     console.log("done pytable ");
 })
 .catch(error =>{
     console.log("Error; " + error);
 });
};
```

result

```
done pytable
```

and pytable is created on database, what i'm doing wrong?

why the db.none statement is not accepting parameters?

**Update**

i dont know why but this works:

```
this.createtablePyme = function(){
 db.any("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $[table:name] ( $[id:name] serial NOT NULL, data jsonb)", {table: 'pytable', id: 'idPyme'})
 .then(()=> 
 {
     console.log("Creada base de datos py");
 })
 .catch(error =>{
     console.log("Error; " + error);
 });
};
```

and using $1:name and pasing values with [] works too.

Comment: `i dont know why but this works:` - try [documentation](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres table names must begin with either a letter or an underscore, per the [documentation](https://etutorials.org/SQL/Postgresql/Part+I+General+PostgreSQL+Use/Chapter+3.+PostgreSQL+SQL+Syntax+and+Use/PostgreSQL+Naming+Rules/).